# How do I do df["col1"].astype(float) with a default for unconvertable values?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code

`f["col1"] = df["col1"].astype(float)`

col1 has values that can't be converted.

How would I do something like this:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].astype(float, default=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) + `fillna`

```
df["col1"]=pd.to_numeric(df["col1"], errors='coerce', downcast='float').fillna(0)
```